# How to use value contained in a variable in some other class

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have a UserDetails class. I have a function in another class B(TableViewController) which contains an object of the UserDetails class, something like this:

```
    -(void)sendData: (UserDetails *) user {

            //some code
      }
```

Now I have another function in a third class C (TableViewController) where I want to use the value contained in the variable "user". How do I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the third class, set up a property of type UserDetails.

When you move from B to C (either in the prepareForSegue or where you init the TVC and push it) just pass the UserDetails object into C so it has its own version.  That way you keep is simple.

Comment: can you tell me the commands..coz I'm getting this message on the console:Unbalanced calls to begin/end appreance transitions for MainViewController . (MainViewController is the parent View Controller which I've created) .

.In the sendData function : -(void)sendData:(UserDetails*) user{ ClassCTableViewController *controller1 = [[ClassCTableViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ClassCTableViewController" bundle:nil]; controller.userObj =user; [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller1 animated:YES]; [controller1 release]; }

Answer (score 0):

In your third class C .h file create a UserDetails object

```
@property (nonatomic,strong) UserDetails * userObj;
```

Then in your class just before where your present/push your third class, **lets say thirdClassObj**, do this

```
thirdClassObj.userObj=user;
```

Comment: I was already doing it...In the sendData function :
-(void)sendData:(UserDetails*) user{
ClassCTableViewController *controller = [[ClassCTableViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ClassCTableViewControlle" bundle:nil];
controller.userObj =user;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:controller1 animated:YES];
[controller1 release];

} 

I am not getting any error but some message is getting printed on the console:
Unbalanced calls to begin/end appreance transitions for MainViewController .

(MainViewController is the parent View Controller which I've created)

Comment: why are you pushing view to controller1 or is that suppose to be controller? even you nib name is wrong

Comment: I dont want to push the view to controlelr1. but if I'm skipping that statement I am getting an exception.

Comment: nib name is just a typo here. :)

Answer (score 0):

I remember answering a similar [**question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7636057/can-i-have-a-single-nsmutablearray-in-my-multiple-views-application/7636155#7636155). Use of [**singleton**](http://www.johnwordsworth.com/2010/04/iphone-code-snippet-the-singleton-pattern/) will be the best approach according to me. You can also see [**my answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6065965/how-to-define-a-global-variable-that-can-be-accessed-anywhere-in-my-application/6067515#6067515) regarding use of singleton for global variables.
You might also use [**appDelegate**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/338734/iphone-proper-usage-of-application-delegate) for this purpose. But I won't recommend using appDelegate. See [**this**](http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/11/singletons-appdelegates-and-top-level.html) for clarification.

Comment: that variable cannot be made global for all the views because its value changes depending on my service URL's.

Comment: @HakunaMatata: Ok. In that case you can save the value in a variable by following the above approach and use it when you need to.