# Where should I implement the facebook login in a tab based app?

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-login, facebook-ios-sdk

I have a tab view controller app which will require to show a login view controller when the user is logged out - when he opens the application for the first time or after he logs out.

What is the best approach? where should I put the code which checks for the session and displays the login view controller?

AppDeledate? one of the tabs? A class for the Tab Bar Controller?

I'm looking for some best practices or a working example of such behaviour.

Thanks!

Comment: If you need a working behaviour, I can help you with some code. Let me know.

Comment: Please find attached the updated Code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Singelton` design is a good approach. For for a login use case, you really need not have to have a `singelton`. You can still go with `Observer` design pattern. `Singleton` is really nice while using CoreData or persistent storage or many operations that needs a common unique controller across the app.

Here is how you can implement the `Observer` pattern.

1. Create A `LoginViewController`.
2. In App Delegate, add an observer method that keeps looking for Session Validity & takes care of presenting LoginController.
3. On `viewDidLoad` of each TabBarController items, perform the Session validity Check.
4. If session is not valid, trigger trigger the notification so that the observer can listen to it & respond accordingly.

This is far simpler approach. In combination with `Singleton`, the `Observer` pattern provides you a robust scalable approach.

**Updated Code**

**----------------------------------------------------------**

Please find `LoginObserver` [Code here](https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/problem-arc/loginObserver.zip)

**----------------------------------------------------------**

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. One problem I faced - If the session is dead I want to show the login view controller, which can't be done from the App Delegate. So I need to open it from each view anyway...

Comment: No no no. The observer pattern is there for this purpose only. You just send a notification that session is expired. The observer implementation should take care of presenting the loginviewcontroller, based on if the app ran for the first time or has already run. Looks like I should give a sample code to support my answer. I will post it after 2hrs.

Comment: @DoronGoldberg : Please find attached the updated Code.

Answer (score 1):

Best approach is use `singleton` concept to do this. Use **singleton** class, and define public method and call it from wherever. It show modularity to your coding. Don't mess this code with viewcontroller or appDelegate( [see this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9213134/is-it-ok-to-place-most-logic-and-models-in-the-appdelegate)).